# Creating an SD disk image from scratch: "you must specify a filesystem type"

Tags: partitioning, mount, sd-card, dd

***The really short version:***

I am trying to create a disk image that includes an MBR/bootloader provided in another image, and one partition with a root filesystem provided in a tarball. Creating the image file, partitioning it, associating it with a loopback using `kpartx`, and applying a filesystem all seem to work, but when I try to mount `/dev/mapper/loopXp1`, mount says `you must specify a filesystem type`. Doing so, of course, doesn't help.

***Details:***

I've seen tons of tutorials on how to make an image from an existing SD and then write it to another, but that would mean making my users download an image that may not match the size of their SD, much of which is just zeros or other junk, since the starting filesystem isn't very full.

Thus, it seems sensible to just have people download a dd of just the bootloader, plus a tarball of the root fs, then run a script that creates an image of the desired size for local distribution.

Unfortunately, although I could swear these steps have worked in the past, I keep running into the problem described above.

Here's exactly what I'm doing:

```
#!/bin/bash
# Adapted from instructions at http://linux-sunxi.org/Bootable_SD_card

# Settings
img_fn=test.img
img_size=2 #Gigs
img_mountpoint="fs"
img_bootsect="bootsect.img"
img_rootfs="rootfs.tar.bz2"

# Start a disk image file
dd if=/dev/zero of=$img_fn bs=1024 count=10 || exit

# Apply the bootloader
dd if=$img_bootsect of=$img_fn bs=1024 seek=8 || exit

# Extend the image to the desired size
truncate -s ${img_size}G $img_fn || exit

# Create one partition that fills the "disk"
# Using '0 -0' or '0 -1' here warns produces a warning that  the
# partition "is not properly aligned for best performance."
parted -s $img_fn 'mklabel msdos mkpart primary 1 -1 print' || exit

# Associate the file with a loopback device
sudo kpartx -a $img_fn || exit

# Get the name of the loopback device
rootfs_dev=/dev/mapper/$(sudo kpartx -l $img_fn | awk '{print $1}')

# Create mountpoint and filesystem, mount the new FS
[ -e $img_mountpoint ] || mkdir -p $img_mountpoint  || exit
sudo mkfs.ext4 $rootfs_dev  || exit

###
### THINGS BREAK HERE 
### mkfs appears to succeed, but mount fails with:
### "mount: you must specify the filesystem type"
###
sudo mount $rootfs_dev $img_mountpoint  || exit

sudo tar -C $img_mountpoint -jxf $img_rootfs  || exit

sudo umount $img_mountpoint
sudo kpartx -d $img_fn
rmdir $img_mountpoint
```

Heres's the complete `bash -x` output if anyone wants it. Note that the outputs of parted and mkfs both suggest that the "disk" is successfully being partitioned and formatted.

If anyone can see what's going wrong here, I would really appreciate hearing about it. Thanks!

```
$ bash -x mkimg.sh
+ img_fn=test.img
+ img_size=2  
+ img_mountpoint=fs
+ img_bootsect=bootsect.img
+ img_rootfs=rootfs.tar.bz2
+ dd if=/dev/zero of=test.img bs=1024 count=10
10+0 records in
10+0 records out
10240 bytes (10 kB) copied, 0.000968263 s, 10.6 MB/s
+ dd if=bootsect.img of=test.img bs=1024 seek=8
254+1 records in
254+1 records out
260260 bytes (260 kB) copied, 0.067996 s, 3.8 MB/s
+ truncate -s 2G test.img
+ parted -s test.img 'mklabel msdos mkpart primary 1 -1 print'
Model:  (file)
Disk /usr/local/tunapanda/provision/x2go_mystery/test.img: 2147MB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/512B
Partition Table: msdos

Number  Start   End     Size    Type     File system  Flags
 1      1049kB  2147MB  2146MB  primary

+ sudo kpartx -a test.img
++ sudo kpartx -l test.img
++ awk '{print $1}'
+ rootfs_dev=/dev/mapper/loop3p1
+ '[' -e fs ']'
+ sudo mkfs.ext4 /dev/mapper/loop3p1
mke2fs 1.42 (29-Nov-2011)
Filesystem label=
OS type: Linux
Block size=4096 (log=2)
Fragment size=4096 (log=2)
Stride=0 blocks, Stripe width=0 blocks
131072 inodes, 524287 blocks
26214 blocks (5.00%) reserved for the super user
First data block=0
Maximum filesystem blocks=536870912
16 block groups
32768 blocks per group, 32768 fragments per group
8192 inodes per group
Superblock backups stored on blocks:
        32768, 98304, 163840, 229376, 294912

Allocating group tables: done
Writing inode tables: done
Creating journal (8192 blocks): done
Writing superblocks and filesystem accounting information: done

+ sudo mount /dev/mapper/loop3p1 fs
mount: you must specify the filesystem type
+ exit
```

Comment: It's been my experience that when mounting a partition of a disk image on a loop device that you must specify an offsetto the aforementioned partition.

Comment: You might want to check the update on my answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Update**: I didn't provide the full correct solution before; what actually worked for me required to use `gparted` as well, which you can't use.

This method should work (I tested it); you can ajdust each step to your needs and automate everything into the script:

1. Create the blank raw image: `dd if=/dev/zero of=/image.img bs=1 count=100000000` (`100MB`)
2. Create the partition table and the partition: `sudo parted -s image.img 'mklabel msdos mkpart primary 2048s 100%'`
3. Create the filesystem: `sudo mkfs.ext4 image.img`

The key here (**I think**) it's the second step: for some reason, during the test I wasn't able to create a working disk image out of a disk image with a bad aligned partition *ever*. Aligning the partition did the trick for me.